# Is there a way to close a subprocess when I open it on previous if statement

Tags: python, subprocess

I am doing a python script that opens another python script when given a command of /starttest1 and I want to close it when the command is /stoptest1

I tried using Popen.terminate() but it gave me an error

```py
if command == '/starttest1':
        extProc = sp.Popen(['python','haha.py'])
    elif command == '/stoptest1':
        sp.Popen.terminate(extProc)
        print("haha.py has been closed")
```

error I encountered:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'extProc' referenced before assignment

the result I want is the haha.py being closed and print "haha.py has been closed"

Comment: you should define your subprocess `extProc` before the `if / else` statement.

Comment: Your indentations are off. Is that what your code looks like or is it just an issue with the SE code formatting?

Comment: Also, the problem propably is in how the code is called. Can you please provide more context?

Comment: I attached my codings here : https://pastebin.com/iSfSJmw1. would look forward to hear up from you

Answer (score 0):

You should to create new thread for control process, for example:

```
import subprocess as sp

process = None

def handler():
    global process
    if command == '/start'
        process = sp.Popen(['python','haha.py'])
    elif command == '/stop':
        if process is not None:
            sp.Popen.terminate(process) # terminate
        # e.g. else send error message "Process is not running"
```

This is not the best example, but at least pay attention to the meaning.

Comment: PS: Your mistake is not that the process is open in the if block, but, most likely, you cannot control it at all, because it controls the main process ...
command is a command line argument? so it does not work

Comment: I actually integrates the script with telepot(a telegram bot api) and the command is something i obtained through communicating with the bot.

Comment: In this case, I think you need to create some kind of global list for storing open processes .. and control them by chat id, for each user separately

Comment: @AmirulIqram I changed the code, look. Thus, each user can run his process separately from others.

Comment: I am getting the hang of it but I think sharing you the codes are better because I am confused where chat.id came from.
Below is my full code:
https://pastebin.com/iSfSJmw1

Comment: I finally understood that you want to seperate it for different user but in my case it will be only for one user,so I changed it to:
elif command == '/starttest1':
        processes.update(sp.Popen(['python','haha.py']))
    elif command == '/stoptest1':
            sp.Popen.terminate(processes)

But i got the error TypeError: 'Popen' object is not iterable.

Comment: @AmirulIqram Then try my updated code, it should work
If you have only one user and one process - then there is no point in creating dict, you can do with one variable that will store the object of the process

Comment: @AmirulIqram Regarding the telegrams API, I advise you to try the library: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI it is many times more convenient

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately the same error still occurs. Will look into the api u mentioned. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

### tl,dr: The conditional blocks do not matter. They do not have their own name spaces so the exception has other reasons.

Python's conditional blocks don't have seperate namespaces. You can access any variables defined inside conditional blocks as if they were defined in your regular program flow. If the condition was not hit and you try to access a variable, a NameError should be raised by the interpreter. So you can simply do this:

```
if command == '/starttest1':
    extProc = sp.Popen(['python','haha.py'])
elif command == '/stoptest1':
    sp.Popen.terminate(extProc)
    print("haha.py has been closed")
```

Depending on who is using your script, you might want to add some handling for the case that extProc does not exist, but the above code, when copy pasted to a Python console, does run and if used in the correct order, won't raise any Exceptions. I think your problem is the way this code is called, since you surely do not copy past it to a console.

You could try what I call "the Java way" and write a class. That is IMO way less Pythonic but it creates a name space around your code and allows for an easy conditional check like this:

```
class Handler(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.extProc = None
    def do(self, command):
        if command == '/starttest1':
            extProc = sp.Popen(['python','haha.py'])
        elif command == '/stoptest1':
            if extProc is not None:
                sp.Popen.terminate(extProc)
                ectProc = None
                print("haha.py has been closed")
            else:
                handle_no_extProc()
```

Don't use this in productiive code though (actually, never write classes with just one method other than `__init__`) but it's a way to ensure that the conditions are not the problem. Do you start the script each time you enter a new command? In that case there is no way to keep the references. You shuld consider the `input` function to get new commands and keep your references. The only other way I know of is to work with lowlevel os-calls but that probably is not what you are looking for.